# BULK INSERT does not fail when file contains commas instead of semicolons when FIRSTROW > 1

Tags: t-sql, csv, bulk-insert

I encountered an issue where I received a CSV file that supposed to be delimited by semicolons (;) but was delimited by commas (,).
Bulk insert called by sqlcmd did not fail but did not insert either. I know that calling xp_cmdshell is not best practice but please don't comment on this.

After investigation I found that it only fails (as expected) when FIRSTROW = 1, but I need a header inside the file.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [title] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [val] [int] NULL
)
```

Format file:

```
12.0
3
1       SQLCHAR              0       4       ";"    1     "id"             ""
2       SQLCHAR              0       10      ";"    2     "title"          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR              0       4       "\r\n"     3     "val"            ""
```

Data file:

```
1,first,0
2,second,2
```

Bulk insert:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(4000);
SET @cmd = 'sqlcmd -b -S <servername> -Q "set nocount on; set dateformat dmy; bulk insert [test_db].[dbo].[test_insert] from ''C:\temp\test_table.csv'' with ( DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', TABLOCK, MAXERRORS = 1000, FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\r\n'', BATCHSIZE = 100000, FORMATFILE = ''C:\temp\test_table.txt'', FIRSTROW = 2 );"';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the command
From

```
, FIELDTERMINATOR = '';''
```

to

```
, FIELDTERMINATOR = '',''
```

This should do the trick

```
BULK INSERT [test_db].[dbo].[test_insert]
FROM 'C:\temp\test_table.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
```

As the ROWTERMINATOR  goes <ou should try it or switch to `\r\n`

Comment: The file is supposed to have semicolons but by mistake it was received with commas. Expected behavior is that BULK INSERT fails. But it neither failed nor inserted the data. I need to see in error log, that there is file that was not loaded to DB.

Comment: try  first the bulk inbsert in ssms and see if you get an error. I added a Version that works with me, you may want have to adpt it, when this runs ok, with a small sample like you presented here. then you can switch to your comand

Comment: Tunny thing is, that I want to get an error, because that is how I expect it to behave when incorrect file is provided. Otherwise I lean to consider it a bug in BULK INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it behaves correctly. While there are no field terminators in the file, BULK INSERT considers whole file as data for first field of the header. Then there is nothing left to INSERT.